# How do I make it so my Windows 10 laptop does not force a screen refresh/redraw when opening the lid?

Tags: windows-10, laptop-display

I have my power settings for closing the lid set to "Do Nothing". In the past when I used this setting on Windows XP & 7 HP & Dell laptops, the screen just went to black when I closed the lid, and then came right back on when I opened it. If the laptop screen had been a separate monitor, it was like I turned the display power off and on. But with my current HP EliteBook running Windows 10, when I re-open the lid, it has to redraw/rescale the screen (e.g., taskbar shrinks to tiny size, windows get un-maximixed). It's clearly not just turning off the display and then turning it back on when I open it again.

The time it takes to re-setup the screen is obnoxious, and given that I daily use some apps with poor DPI awareness, this sometimes puts my display is a wonky state. This whole redraw action just seems unnecessary.

Is there any way at the Windows or hardware level to make it truly "do nothing"?

(There are no other monitors involved here, I'm just using the laptop by itself.)

Comment: Not a duplicate, since in my scenario there are 0 other monitors involved.

Comment: The suggested solution still applies.